# Updating Target Action Method of Player remote control events (MPRemoteCommand)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, mpremotecommandcenter

I have created application with two different audio players (Radio and MP3). Using MPRemoteCommandCenter for both players for managing players from lock screen. Here is the code snippet:

**MP3 Player**

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()  
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(next))
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previous))
commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPause)
commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPause))
```

**Radio Player**

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self, action:nil)
commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(radioPlayFromLock))
commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self, action:nil)
commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(radioJPStop))
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
```

Both are working correctly individually but once follow these steps:

1. Play MP3 player
2. after that play Radio
3. and trying to stop from lock screen
4. List item

is crashing due to looking for MP3 player method. That mean target method is not updated for play/pause command. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self, action:nil)
```

use this:

```
commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(nil)//this actually removes your targets
```

From Apple documentation:

> Specify nil to remove all targets.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand/1622903-removetarget

Comment: Adding a little prose around the answer would improve clarity. I was initially confused what the answer was without reading it a few times.